# Confusion with classbalancing pipeline in 'mlr3pipelines' when using resample

Tags: r, mlr3

I am very confused about how the 'classbalancing' pipeline operates, specifically during resampling with 'resample'.

I am performing a binary logistic regression using a large dataset, and would like to downsample my major class while performing training (and ideally testing as well).

When I perform downsampling outside of the 'resample' function, I get the expected result (major class frequencies equal to 5 times the minor class).

**Setup**

```
task_lr <- TaskClassif$new('task_lr', backend = data.df, target = 'ls')
```

**Without resample**

```
opb <- po('classbalancing', adjust = 'downsample', reference = 'minor', ratio = 5) %>>% po("encode", method = "treatment") %>>%
  po("scale") %>>% lrn("classif.cv_glmnet", predict_sets = c("test", "train"))
opb$keep_results <- TRUE
opbLearner <- as_learner(opb)
opbResult <- opbLearner$train(task_lr)
opbResult$graph$pipeops$classbalancing$.result$output
```

Outputted graph data has dimensions of 702 x 16 as desired

**With resample**

```
resampleTest <- mlr3::resample(task = task_lr, opbLearner, resampling = rsmp("subsampling", ratio = 0.7, repeats = 1))
resampleTest$learners[[1]]$graph$pipeops$classbalancing$.result$output
```

Outputted graph data has dimensions of 2541608 x 16

EDIT

When performing with a resampling ratio of 1, it gives the correct dataset size under the graph.

```
resampleTest <- mlr3::resample(task = task_lr, opbLearner, resampling = rsmp("subsampling", ratio = 1, repeats = 1))
resampleTest$learners[[1]]$graph$pipeops$classbalancing$.result$output
```

Output is 702 x 16 in dimensions as desired

My question comes down to if it is possible to perform the resampling as done in the resample function on the dataset after the pipe operators have modified it. However, it is still confusing to me how the resample function works as I want when a subsampling ratio of 1 is given.